# Radial distribution to cartesian coordinates

Tags: distributions, matlab

I'm trying to go from a radial distribution in polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates. I'm using Matlab and have tried pol2cart, but are having some trouble getting a matrix with probabilities.

The distribution is a log-normal along the radius, homogenous along theta.What I'd like to have is a 2D matrix with the probabilities so I could plot a heat map or similar, getting something like this: [image]

Thank you in advance,
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will get you started. Here's how to define an anonymous function that computes the radius from x and y, and another that computes the density. If you don't have the `lognpdf` function from the Statistics Toolbox, you can probably figure out how to program that yourself.

```
r = @(x,y) sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
f = @(x,y) lognpdf(r(x,y),1,.3)./(2*pi*r(x,y));
integral2(f,-10,10,-10,10)
ezsurf(f,[-5,5])
```